# React Router (v6) fail to load programmatic routes on reload or manual route typing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom, redux-thunk

I'm trying to do programmatic routing on project using :
react - redux (plain redux) - **react router v6** - typescript
also using Vite not CRA (if this can help)

Bellow is simple version of my code:

> App.tsx

```js
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
<Route element={<Layout />}>
  <Route path="/" element={<itemsList />} />
  <Route path="/item">
    <Route path="/item/:itemId" element={<itemComponent />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
</Route>
</Routes>   
</BrowserRouter>
```

> ItemComponent

```js
  const { itemId } = useParams();

const items = items.find((item) => {
    return item.id === itemId;
  });

  if (!item) {
    return <>{'Sorry!!!, Item Not Found'}</>;
  }

/* and the code for this certain (itemId) */
```

everything seems to worked fine i can navigate to the
`/item/:itemId` route with no problems
But then comes the issue:
if i tried to refresh the page i get the `{'Sorry!!!, Item Not Found'}` that i put there if no item
also, if i tried to go to the `itemId` page manually i get same error

I searched and found some solutions but non worked and most were outdated
I appreciate the help and let me know if u need any more information

**EDIT:** Adding more info and codes
the `items` is data I'm fetching from fake json-server using redux-thunk (i was fetching it in ItemsList component but after research I'm fetching it directly from store using following code and its the only place im doing list fetch)

```js
import { store } from './store';
import App from './App';
import { fetchItems } from './action-creators';
import { ItemsActions, ItemsState } from './types/';
import { ThunkDispatch } from 'redux-thunk';

(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<ItemsState, unknown, ItemsActions>)(
  fetchItems()
);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

> itemsList sample

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "userId": "1",
      "id": "1",
      "title": "item Title",
      "body": "item body"
    },
   {
      "userId": "1",
      "id": "2",
      "title": "item Title2",
      "body": "item body2"
    }
}
```

> fetchItems action code :

```
export const fetchItems = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<ItemsActions>) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'FETCH_ITEMS',
    });

    try {
      const {data} = await axios.get(basefetchItemsURL);

      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_SUCCESS',
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_ITEMS_ERROR',
          payload: err.message,
        });
      }
    }
  };
};
```

With above setup i can for example go to routes("/" or "/item" ) it work fine and `itemsList is fetched normally  Also i can go to (path="/item/:itemId") from the` ItemsList `component But once im on this page (path="/item/:itemId") example: (http://localhost:3000/item/1) and i refresh the page it get lost and i get error (tsx:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined) and the itemsList also lost and i get empty array`[]`

Comment: `itemComponent` isn't a valid React component, it should be Capitalized, i.e. `ItemComponent`. What is `items` in the `ItemComponent` component? Please share a more complete [mcve].

Comment: items is an array of objects, i found out the cause of problem that i needed to fetch items from store directly

Comment: Do you still need hep with this at all?

Comment: yes i found away to in another post here to fetch items :
```

(store.dispatch as ThunkDispatch<ItemssState, unknown, ItemsActions>)(
  fetchitems()
);
```
but its now giving me error still that post not exist
"'item'  is undefined

Comment: So again I ask, what is `items` supposed to be in this other component? Is it a static asset that is imported? Something you are storing in the redux store and need to select in the component? Something else? Have you already fetched these items once elsewhere in the app? If so, isn't it a bit silly to refetch them again in a detail page? If you need more help still then please do edit the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve].

Comment: post edited , sorry for any inconvenience, hopefully  the new data is more helpful 
really appreciate you trying to help

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemComponent` component appears to correctly handle the "sad path" when the `item` object is undefined/falsey either because `items` is an empty array or because no matching element was found via the predicate function's condition.

I think the issue is that the `fetchItems` action isn't dispatched when the app has been mounted, as part of the React component lifecycle. This ensures the `react-redux` `Provider` component is mounted and has a `store` object to provide to the app.

Try dispatching `fetchItems` from a `useEffect` hook in the `App` component when it mounts.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchItems()); // <-- dispatch when App mounts
  }, []);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<ItemsList />} />
          <Route path="/item/:itemId" element={<ItemComponent />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>   
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Similarly I suspect you might be accessing the store directly in the routed component file. You should also be selecting the `items` array from the Redux store within the React component lifecycle. Here you can use the `useSelector` hook to select the appropriate state slice.

ItemComponent

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const ItemComponent = () => {
  const items = useSelector(state => state.items); // *

  const { itemId } = useParams();

  const items = items.find((item) => item.id === itemId);

  if (!item) {
    return <>Sorry!!!, Item Not Found</>;
  }

  ...
};
```

* ***Note:** Here selecting `state.items` assumes this is how you've configured the store and have a combined reducer named `items`. You'll need to select the items state from the reducer path for how you've structured your combined state tree.*

Comment: sadly i did try useEffect but i get the same error as (fetched items still get lost),
i'm trying to fetch directly from store since `store.dispatch(fetchItems())` worked like charm in (Non-typescript) version, so now i think the problem got somthing to do with typescript missing with redux persisting data ability some how
also i do use typed version of useSelector to access state.items

Comment: @MaximoConn Ah, yeah, that is also the issue of persisting any current redux state. Have you explored [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) at all? In the meantime think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live? As for the `useSelector` typing, you'd export the state type, something like `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;` and then do something like `const items: Items = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.items);`.

Comment: i gave ( redux-persist) a go it did work as expected , but with a new issue, the images and svg's don't persist ( looking for a solution for this atm)
its just wired and depressing not able too figure out why the work fine without need to persist to localstorage in the vanilla java script version and failing in the typescript version
anyway thank you very much for helping me out

Comment: @MaximoConn Images should either be assets built into the app (*i.e. imported*) or should be considered content, not "state" at all. FWIW I wouldn't expect to store images in localStorage unless you are stringifying them to base64 or similar. The browser should be caching fetched images though where it can.